# snakefile can not be found even it is defined in profile

Tags: snakemake

I created a profile like the following in profileRNASeq/config.yaml:

`snakefile: Snakefile-RNASeq
jobscript: ../jobscript.sh
latency-wait: 60
reason: True
show-failed-logs: True

...`

As in the profile, the snakefile is pointing to "Snakefile-RNASeq", there is always an error when run the following:

`$ snakemake --profile profileRNASeq/ Error: no Snakefile found, tried Snakefile, snakefile, workflow/Snakefile, workflow/snakefile.`

I wonder why "Snakefile-RNASeq" was not read in as 'snakefile' by the snakemake.

Thanks,

Jack

I tried to run $ snakemake --profile profileRNASeq/ and expected to see snakefile value is picked up by snakemake from the profile.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the snakefile is parsed before the profile is read in, though what you propose is reasonable.

- You can open an issue on github to see if others agree it should be implemented.
- You can change you workflow name to adhere to best practice.  In particular, you can have a dummy `Snakefile` which just imports your pipeline.
- You can use a profile and a snakefile option `snakemake --profile profileRNASeq --snakefile Snakefile-RNASeq`
- It is also possible the snakefile you specify is relative to the profile, instead of the execution directory.  E.g. change your config.yaml to

```
snakefile: ../Snakefile-RNASeq
```

I would use `Snakefile` to adhere to standards, unless I had a really good reason not to.